How would a woman address a beau in the 19th century if he were higher class?
I'm trying to find out if a middle class woman who was being courted by an upper class gentleman, would address the man as 'sir' prior to their engagement.

Woman, 18 years old, middle class.
Man 28 years old, upper class, wealthy.

He's not engaged and is courting her.
Would she still address him as sir?

Didn't this exact scenario happen in Pride and Prejudice? IIRC, Elisabeth usually referred to him as "Mr. Darby"

@T.E.D. Elizabeth Bennet and Mr. Darcy are both landed gentry and social equals.

@KillingTime - They most certainly were not social equals. His mother certainly didn't see it that way. He was slumming just to be hanging at the same social event with her. That was kind of the entire point of the book. Before him, the best her family thought they could do for her was a priest, and her next-door neighbor was giddy to get that same priest.

@T.E.D Austen considered them social equals. When Lady Catherine says that Darcy would be marrying beneath his position, Elizabeth defiantly says "He is a gentleman; I am a gentleman’s daughter; so far we are equal."

Since the question is tagged "19th-century" and "American", it's unlikely that a novel based on at the very start of the century set in England would be a prime example of what Amy was after.

@T.E.D. - If you mean Lady Catherine de Bourgh, she wasn't Darcy's mother - his aunt, I think.

People certainly were careful to use 'correct' forms of address, even to their social equals.

@SteveBird - That's a good point. I didn't notice the tag, and kind of assumed it would be applicable because England actually at the time had a much more defined sense of "class" than the USA, so the question makes much more sense that way. It would be a fiction to say the USA was a classless society then, but a lot of Americans certainly liked to think of themselves that way. That leaves me wondering if the OQ meant "higher class than her" or "upper class" (and perhaps she was as well). Could we perhaps get an edit on this point?

Not too sure about US usage, but I would imagine the woman would simply use "Mr Smith" rather than "Sir". "Sir" would possibly place her in the servant class - not middle class. OTOH, I think sir and ma'am are /were more prevalent in the US. Maybe depends just how large the class divide is, I suspect.

I read it in French a long time ago as "Les quatre filles du Dr. March", but what about Little Women?  4 suitors, one ought to fit somewhat

@TheHonRose - Addressing someone as 'Sir' did not necessarily imply that the speaker considered themself socially inferior to the person addressed. In the 18th century James Boswell quoted himself and Dr Johnson as addressing one another as 'Sir'.

@KateBunting Yes, in the 18th century. I think the 19th was marginally less formal. People would use "Sir", "Madam" or  "Ma'am" in certain circumstances, but I don't think a young woman being courted would use it all the time.

In the 19th century, books about social etiquette, especially in the parts related to women addressing men (and conversly), recommend using "Mr so-and-so" or "Mrs so-and-so", with additional advice for family or people with titles, such as President, Doctor, Congressman...

The lady's guide to perfect gentility, in manners, dress, and conversation by Emily Thornwell
Manners and social usages by Mrs John Sherwood


“Do not use the surname alone when speaking of your husband or wife to others. To say to another, that “I told Jones,” referring to your husband, sounds badly, whereas, to say, “I told Mr. Jones,” shows respect and good breeding. Etiquette of Conversation (19th Century U.S.A.)

The above seems to be the norm ("shows respect and good breeding") whenever a woman talks to/of a man. It shouldn't be so different if the man is courting the woman though.

A nice and well-founded answer!
